# Building custom RouteLink for Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

`/posts/b/1` loads posts from Blog with id 1

`/posts/b/-1` loads all posts from all blogs

How to configure the route to use `/posts` to load all posts from all blogs?

I use redirection to `RouterModule.forRoot` but i have problem with `[routerLinkActive]`

Comment: just create two separate routes.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question : can you provide a example Plunkr exposing your problem, or at least your relevant code ?

Comment: i want conditional `RouteLink`, if  `someVariable` is null or -1 then use `/posts` and not `posts/b/-1`

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't know if conditional RouteLink is possible, however in the component handling the route with 'id' parameter, you can check the id and the redirect to the other route.

Comment: an easy implementation is to use function `[RouterLink]="[buildLink()]"` but i don't know if it is suggested. There is a global variable `currentBlog`. If it is -1 function will return `/posts` , else `/posts/b/:id`

Comment: global variable doesn't sound good. But it's hard to guess what you did exactly, please provide a minimal example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Th order of the route matters kindly find the below sample

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path:'products',component:ProductListComponent},
      {path:'products/:id',
      canActivate:[ProductDetailGuard],
      component:ProductDetailComponent
    },
      {path:'welcome',component:WelcomeComponent},
      {path:'',redirectTo:'welcome',pathMatch:'full'},
      {path:'**',redirectTo:'welcome',pathMatch:'full'}


    ])
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using : `this.router.navigate()`

In the component supposed to handle your route with `/posts/b/{id}`, you can use ActivatedRoute to get the current route parameter and act accordingly.

You should do something like that :

```
constructor(protected route: ActivatedRoute) {}

void checkRoute() {
    route.params.Subscribe(
        params => {
            let id = params['id']; // use the name of your route parameter
            if (!(id > 0)) {
                // redirect here with router.navigate()
            }
        }
    );
 }
```

disclaimer : haven't checked this exact code, sorry if syntax / typos.

call the function checkRoute() whenever you want, in constructor probably.

Comment: yea i tried something like this but am new and i don't know if this is good or bad practice

Comment: Th usual way for APIs "REST"-style, is to access a specific element with /posts/X where X is your id, and access a page listing all the posts with /posts , as you did.
For invalid IDs, like /posts/-1 or /posts/Y (where post with id Y doesn't exist), I would recommend simply redirecting to a 404 page ("page not found").